# Windows Updates GDR vs LDR (QFE)

Tags: windows, patch, windows-update, hotfix, automatic-updates

While going through the information present at [Windows Hotfixes and Updates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/10/21/windows-hotfixes-and-updates-how-do-they-work.aspx) website, I understood that Windows maintains two different branches to provide Updates and Hotfixes and as per the description,

1. GDR -> All Windows Updates fall into this category.
2. LDR (QFE) -> All Hotfixes fall into this category.

While retrieving the

1. Windows update information with [Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and
2. Hotfix/LDR/QFE information with WMIC QFE GET

I found that some of the KB numbers are common in Windows Update/ Hotfix. How could this be possible?
As per the description regarding GDR and LDR, it says

> By default, all components on Windows systems start on the GDR branch
> following each major release. When you install updates from Windows
> Update for a GDR component, it gets upgraded with the GDR version.
> When you install a specific Hotfix, the files and components in the
> Hotfix package are migrated to the LDR branch. At this point, that
> particular component is marked as a LDR component. If you install a
> newer Update over this component, the Windows servicing technology
> will automatically install the appropriate latest version from the LDR
> branch for you.

Could someone help me understand whats the reason for KB Number common in both Update and Hotfix information?

Comment: KB numbers is practically a problem ID. A confirmed problem which was found by either Microsoft, users, or third parties.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the information. I actually found that Microsoft stores Updates (GDR) and Hotfixes (LDR/QFE) separately. So for me to get all installed KB numbers, I should be querying both for GDR and LDR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer in MSDN forum.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/a8538737-ecb6-4981-bed0-4ef3cb9356d7